# How can I select from items from two tables with one item only have one value

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

**Table A**:

```
Item_Number  EVENT_ID
```

**Table B**:

```
EVENT_ID  EVENT_TYPE_ID
```

The `EVENT_ID`s are unique and they are the same in two tables. `EVENT_TYPE_ID` have different values from 1-100. But I'm only interested in the EVENT_TYPE_ID=40 and EVENT_TYPE_ID=41. So I used an inner join to pick out those items that only has EVENT_TYPE_ID=40 or EVENT_TYPE_ID=41.

```
SELECT  
    ITEM_NUMBER, EVENT_TYPE_ID 
FROM
    A
INNER JOIN
    B ON A.EVENT_ID = B.EVENT_ID 
WHERE 
    EVENT_TYPE_ID = 40 or EVENT_TYPE_ID = 41
```

I got some results like this:

```
Item_Number     Event_Type_ID
-----------------------------
1004            40
1019            41
1002            41
1109            40
1004            41
1004            40
1019            40
1002            41
1109            40
```

These Items, some have only events whose type=40, some have only events whose type=41, some have both 40 and 41 types of events. Now I want to pick up those items who only have events type 40 or 41, but not have both these two events. How should I write the query?

Comment: Does it matter if the event has event types other than 40 or 41?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest simpler solution using `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER, COUNT(ITEM_NUMBER) COUNT_ITEM_NUMBER
from A  
INNER Join B ON A.EVENT_ID=B.EVENT_ID 
WHERE EVENT_TYPE_ID IN (40, 41)
GROUP BY ITEM_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(ITEM_NUMBER) = 1;
```

You can make after that another join, if you wish to know EVENT_TYPE_ID on records, like

```
SELECT GROUPED.ITEM_NUMBER, B.EVENT_TYPE_ID
FROM (
  SELECT ITEM_NUMBER, COUNT(ITEM_NUMBER) COUNT_ITEM_NUMBER
  from A  
  INNER Join B ON A.EVENT_ID=B.EVENT_ID 
  WHERE EVENT_TYPE_ID (40, 41)
  GROUP BY ITEM_NUMBER
  HAVING COUNT(ITEM_NUMBER) = 1 ) GROUPED
INNER Join B ON GROUPED.EVENT_ID=B.EVENT_ID
WHERE EVENT_TYPE_ID (40, 41)
```

Comment: No need to have distinct, as we already have filtering in where, and we group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join trick:

```
select A.ITEM_NUMBER, B.EVENT_TYPE_ID
from A
join B on A.EVENT_ID=B.EVENT_ID
    and B.EVENT_TYPE_ID IN (40,41)
left join B B2 on A.EVENT_ID=B2.EVENT_ID
    and B2.EVENT_TYPE_ID IN (40,41)
    and B2.EVENT_TYPE_ID != B.EVENT_TYPE_ID
where B2.EVENT_TYPE_ID is null
```

This does an outer join to B on the *other* event type, and filters *out* rows where there are both types.

Comment:  I like this approach :)